# why select query return all table data with file data in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table using SQL Template, insert rows and fetch the data from newly created table in Athena. I gave a s3 location which already have a csv file with some data. I'm getting all the data(csv files data and table data which I inserted using insert query). I want to fetch only table data not others files data. Why this behavior is happening? I attached the screenshot of my query and s3 location.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `LOCATION 's3:://some-location';` line, dont you want to add in there the exact file you want to build a table from?

i.e. `LOCATION 's3:://some-location/the-file.csv';

Comment: No, I don't want to build a table from a exact file. I want a simple table and insert some rows and fetch that rows with out fetch any data from other files which are not mentioned in table creation time. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: The easiest way is to use different folders for different tables. Adding include/exclude flags is not simple and it is fragile